# react: login button falling to redirect login/logout

Tags: reactjs, authentication

hello im really new to react. im creating a login and logout option in react and have the fetch in place however i am not able to get the redirect for the onclick logout and login button to function here is the code snippit what am i doing wrong

[the fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZxfV.png)

[the imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlIKT.png)

[the body of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe7aW.png)

[the onChange event entered into the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XLX4.png)

Comment: You can paste your relevant code directly in your question using the code markdown. It's way more readable imo :)

Comment: Your PostData promise nver resolves?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `PostData` promise. Looks like it's never resolves and has one more issue with return data. You need to slightly modify this. Merge both of `.this()` into one with a following code:

```
...
.then((response) => 
    sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', response.text());
    resolve(response.data);
)
```